# Use my photo for a search by image

Tags: search, images, google-image-search

How may I use a photo which is on my computer, for a search by image? I have already tried to upload it to my Google+ Unlimited account.

Comment: If memory serves, if you're using Chrome you can drag-and-drop the file on the search input field, for Google Image Search, at least.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options. One here: https://www.tineye.com/

[image: TinEye home page]

Another here: https://www.google.com/imghp:

[image: Google Images home page]

Then, in Google, if you click on the camera icon:

[image: Google Images camera pop-up]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Chrome as a browser
2. Go to www.google.com
3. Click on the Images link (currently on the right side near the gear
   wheel etc)
4. Click on the camera icon that is now in your Search bar
5. Click on the Upload an Image tab
6. Click on Choose File:   this opens a file navigation window - on it,
   choose the file on your computer.
7. Click Ok